# Tizen Watch and iOS Connectivity Problems

Tags: ios, tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-wearable-sdk

My requirement is to create an application which transfer text from iOS device to Tizen Wearable. As per tizen documents I have used BLE for communication.
On our end architecture would be Tizen as central and iOS as peripheral where initial connection will be from tizen to iOS app.

**For Tizen:**

```
var remoteDevice = null;
var adapter = tizen.bluetooth.getLEAdapter();



function onDeviceFound(device) {
     if (remoteDevice === null) {
       remoteDevice = device;
       console.log('Found device ' + device.name + '. Connecting...');
      device.connect(connectSuccess, connectFail);
    }
 adapter.stopScan();
 }

function connectFail(error) {
    console.log('Failed to connect to device: ' + e.message);
}

function connectSuccess() {
    console.log('Connected to device');
    var serviceUUIDs = remoteDevice.uuids;
    **var gattService = remoteDevice.getService(serviceUUIDs[0]); //error in this one**
    var property = gattService.characteristics[0];
}

adapter.startScan(onDeviceFound);
```

**For iOS BLE connection:**

```
private func setupPeripheral() {
   let transferCharacteristic = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: TransferService.characteristicUUID, properties: [.notify, .writeWithoutResponse],value: nil,permissions: [.readable, .writeable])
   let transferService = CBMutableService(type: TransferService.serviceUUID, primary: true)
    transferService.characteristics = [transferCharacteristic]
    peripheralManager.add(transferService)
    self.transferCharacteristic = transferCharacteristic
}

peripheralManager.startAdvertising([CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey: [TransferService.serviceUUID]])

func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
        switch peripheral.state {
        case .poweredOn:
            os_log("CBManager is powered on")
            setupPeripheral()
        case .poweredOff:
            os_log("CBManager is not powered on")
            return
        case .resetting:
            os_log("CBManager is resetting")
            return
        case .unauthorized:
           os_log("Unexpected authorization")
            return
        case .unknown:
            os_log("CBManager state is unknown")
            return
        case .unsupported:
            os_log("Bluetooth is not supported on this device")
            return
        @unknown default:
            os_log("A previously unknown peripheral manager state occurred")
            return
        }
    }
    func peripheralManager(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, central: CBCentral, didSubscribeTo characteristic: CBCharacteristic) {
  os_log("Central subscribed to characteristic")
        connectedCentral = central
    }
func peripheralManager(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, central: CBCentral, didUnsubscribeFrom characteristic: CBCharacteristic) {
    os_log("Central unsubscribed from characteristic")
    connectedCentral = nil
}
```

By implementing **remoteDevice.getService(remoteDevice.uuids[0])** code I am getting error **device not found exception.**

Same issue has been posted in this link also:
https://developer.tizen.org/ko/forums/web-application-development/central-peripharal-client-server-architecture-ble-communication-tizen-wearable-ios-not-working?langredirect=1

If someone have faced similar kind of challenge and found required solution then please provide your valuable inputs as it is kind of blocker on our end.

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am a Tizen developer and have never developed an iOS app. I assume that the iOS app:

- creates a GATT server with *TransferService* UUID
- starts advertising *TransferService* UUID
- only advertises *TransferService* UUID (i.e. it should be in remoteDevice.uuids[0] in the Tizen app code)
- allows a BLE client to connect to the server
  You can verify, that the app works as assumed with [nRF Connect app](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Software-and-tools/Development-Tools/nRF-Connect-for-mobile).

Please, ensure that your Tizen device finds the Apple BLE device, you want to connect, in the scan.
Your Tizen app connects to the first BLE device it finds. It is OK as long as the Apple device is the only visible BLE device.
To be sure, that the Tizen client connects to the proper device, you need to filter out other devices in your `onDeviceFound`. For example, connect to the device with a particular Bluetooth name:

```
function onDeviceFound(device) {
  if (device.name=== [iOS BLE device name]) {
    remoteDevice = device;
    console.log('Found device ' + device.name + '. Connecting...');
    device.connect(connectSuccess, connectFail);
  }
  adapter.stopScan();
}
```

Comment: Hi Brian, 
Thanks for your feedback. 
We followed the similar steps on our end,

1) From iOS Side - I have created transferService UUID & advertising it. On Android side we are getting device ID too in onDeviceFound delegate / method. 

2) After that I am trying to connect with the device: 

var serviceUUIDs = remoteDevice.uuids; //** here I am getting the service id.
var gattService = remoteDevice.getService(serviceUUIDs[0]); 

But when I try to fetch TransferServiceID - I am getting error "device not found exception".

It will be helpful if you can share your inputs on the same.

Comment: On my setup (server and advertising done with nRF Connect app and Tizen device) the code works just fine - Android device is found and its service is retrieved. Please, check if `remoteDevice.uuids[0]` contains the UUID of the transfer service. Before calling `remoteDevice.getService(<UUID>`, please check, that the `remoteDevice.name` is the name of your iOS device that operates the service.